# Is it possible to automate unit test creation in PHP 7.2?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Given I use a specific code style of PHP 7.2 and hint all types of arguments and return values, is it possible to give the job of writing unit tests to a program? It could save me a lot of time and reduce bug numbers. I could change the design and give up method chains and follow rigorously the Low of Demetere to simplify the automation. Unit tests are of greate value as well as time is.

Comment: Your tests do not need test PHP language features, so even this is (technically) possible, what would be the use of it if I may ask? I can imagine this could be useful for fuzzing functions and classes but whole unit tests apart from that?

Comment: I write a lot unit tests because they help find bugs and make refactoring less dangerous. My class methods are very small, so the unit tests have little complexity. And I see my work is mechanical. After a look on a line of code I know what lines I'll put in my current unit test. PHP 7.x features make us not so much dependent on PHPDOC. If an argument type is present in method signature there's no problem to create a mock.